# Normalizing Wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, complex-numbers, normalization

**An unnormalized wavefunction for a light atom rotating around a heavy atom to which it is bonded is ${\psi(\phi)}$ = $e^{i \phi}$ with $0 \le$ ${\phi}$ $\le$ ${2\pi}$. Normalize this wavefunction**

I have attempted to solve this problem as below

$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i \phi} (e^{i \phi})^* d \phi$

= $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i \phi} e^{-i \phi} d \phi$

= $\int_0^{2\pi} d \phi$

= 0

However, I am unable to derive anything meaningful out of this result

Could someone explain what I did wrong?

$*$ is complex conjugation.

Comment: Tip: use `\le` and `\ge` for $\le$ and $\ge$, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the following wrong:

$e^0$ is not Zero

$e^0 = 1$

Comment: However, the integral from 0 to 2pi is 0 - at 2pi it equals 1 and at 0 it equals 1 therefore the difference is 0

Comment: You have $\int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi = [\phi]_0^{2 \pi}$

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi=2\pi$.

Answer (score -1):

You must have a constant with your wave function to normalise it .after integrating you will get integral as |A|^2*2pi . Which has to be 1.so you get A=1/(2pi)^1÷2

Comment: You should typeset your answer.

Comment: It's mobile.. i can do nothing